# Excel Macros: Check for duplicates and copy only selected cells in unique rows (RemoveDuplicate didn't help)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Please refer to the below:

[image]

In Excel, I want to copy value of highlighted letters `(A,C,F,G,I)` of those rows which are marked with a different reference number and if the reference number is same, I can choose any random reference number and copy its values.

Example: Since Ref no 1 is in cell `A2` and `A3` I can choose the highlighted column `(A,C,F,G,I)` values from any row (either `A2` or `A3`).

So copied values will be from rows `((A2 or A3) AND (A4) AND (A5 or A6 or A7) AND (A8))`

Once I copy these values, I want to move to another sheet (Sheet2) from the current sheet (Sheet 1) and paste it. But wait.. In the Sheet2, I want the paste to happen something like this [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9zXu.png)

I need to skip a few columns because a different value will go in those columns.

This is my attempt:

```
Sub Import()

Sheets("Procurement Plan ->PM40").Activate
Dim Val1 As Integer
Dim Val2 As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To 8
    'For j = i + 1 To i + 2

        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
            'copy row i
            Sheets("Procurement Plan ->PM40").Range("A" & i & ",C" & i & ",D" & i & ",E" & i & ",I" & i & ",J" & i & ",N" & i & ",AX" & i & ",BD" & i & ",BE" & i & ",BG" & i).Copy Sheets("Management Summary ->PM40").Range("A40")
        Else
            'i = i + 1
            'copy row j

        End If
    'Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

How can I refine it or make a more efficient solution altogether?

Comment: Why does not it matter if you copy row 2 or 3? What factors do you use to determine that it does not matter if I copy row 2 or 3 when values at (A,C,F,G,I) are different?

Comment: Also, Check PivotTables. It's indeed the fastest way to group your data and show only the columns you want, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtSsu.jpg If you can fin a criteria to determine which row to use, then probably you can apply your criteria to PivotTable and get the data as you want

Comment: In my case it doesn't matter. The excel provided is just for reference. It's not actual data.

Comment: I understand, but you need a criteria to choose a row, even if it's not actual data.

Comment: Yes the criteria is, `if same reference number, choose any row, if difference referency number, simply copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    'False = append results on each macro run
    'True = Overwrite previous results on each macro run
    Const bOverwrite As Boolean = True

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim dictUnqRef As Object
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aTemp As Variant
    Dim sRefCol As String
    Dim lRefCol As Long
    Dim lColIndex As Long
    Dim lMinCol As Long
    Dim lMaxCol As Long
    Dim lRandIndex As Long
    Dim lNumRows As Long
    Dim lDestRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Adjust these parameters to suit
    sRefCol = "A"
    Dim aColumnSourceDest(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As String
        aColumnSourceDest(1, 1) = "B":  aColumnSourceDest(1, 2) = "B"
        aColumnSourceDest(2, 1) = "D":  aColumnSourceDest(2, 2) = "C"
        aColumnSourceDest(3, 1) = "G":  aColumnSourceDest(3, 2) = "E"
        aColumnSourceDest(4, 1) = "H":  aColumnSourceDest(4, 2) = "H"
        aColumnSourceDest(5, 1) = "J":  aColumnSourceDest(5, 2) = "I"

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Procurement Plan ->PM40")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Management Summary ->PM40")
    Set dictUnqRef = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lDestRow = 2

    lMinCol = wsData.Columns(sRefCol).Column
    For lColIndex = LBound(aColumnSourceDest, 1) To UBound(aColumnSourceDest, 1)
        If wsData.Columns(aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 1)).Column < lMinCol Then lMinCol = wsData.Columns(aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 1)).Column
        If wsData.Columns(aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 1)).Column > lMaxCol Then lMaxCol = wsData.Columns(aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 1)).Column
    Next lColIndex
    lRefCol = wsData.Columns(sRefCol).Column - lMinCol + 1
    For lColIndex = LBound(aColumnSourceDest, 1) To UBound(aColumnSourceDest, 1)
        aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 3) = wsData.Columns(aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 1)).Column - lMinCol + 1
    Next lColIndex


    With wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(2, lMinCol), wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, lMinCol).End(xlUp).Offset(-2)).Resize(, lMaxCol - lMinCol + 1)
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        aData = .Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If Not dictUnqRef.exists(aData(i, lRefCol)) Then
            dictUnqRef(aData(i, lRefCol)) = i
        Else
            dictUnqRef(aData(i, lRefCol)) = dictUnqRef(aData(i, lRefCol)) & "," & i
        End If
    Next i

    If bOverwrite Then
        wsDest.Range("A13").Resize(wsDest.Rows.Count - 12, wsDest.Columns.Count).ClearContents
        lDestRow = 13
    Else
        lDestRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, aColumnSourceDest(1, 2)).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If

    For Each vKey In dictUnqRef.keys
        aTemp = Split(dictUnqRef(vKey), ",")
        lNumRows = UBound(aTemp) - LBound(aTemp) + 1
        Randomize
        lRandIndex = Int(Rnd() * lNumRows)
        For lColIndex = LBound(aColumnSourceDest, 1) To UBound(aColumnSourceDest, 1)
            wsDest.Cells(lDestRow, aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 2)).Value = aData(aTemp(lRandIndex), aColumnSourceDest(lColIndex, 3))
        Next lColIndex
        lDestRow = lDestRow + 1
    Next vKey

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `Dim aColumnSourceDest(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As String` mean? Please explain the parameters

Comment: I want the copy in the destination file to start from A13. What change do I gotta make in the code? Thanks

Comment: @PriyankaDembla The `1 to 5` is how many rows the array holds and the `1 to 3` is how many columns the array holds.  Each row is for a specific column Source and Destination pair.  The source column letter goes in column one of the array (which is why the left half is `(1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1)` etc) and the destination column letter goes in column two of the array (which is why the right half is `(1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 2)` etc).  The third column is reserved for the code to identify column index numbers of the source column

Comment: @PriyankaDembla As for getting the copy in the destination to start at row 13, I  have edited the answer to change how the `lDestRow` variable gets assigned.  It will now start at row 13 if `bOverwrite` is True.  If `bOverwrite` is False, then the data will get appended to existing data instead.

Comment: Ok I understand. Also, where in the code are you getting the range of rows? Like I want all rows but the last 2. Example: If range is `1 to 5` I want to select `1 to 3`. Because my last 2 rows are comments. So no need to copy them. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @PriyankaDembla I have edited the answer so that now it will ignore the last two rows of data.  This was done by adding `.Offset(-2)` in the `With wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(2, lMinCol), ...` line

Comment: Hello @tigeravatar . Hope you're doing good. Kindly look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018220/check-row-condition-to-copy-and-paste-from-1-workbook-to-the-other   It's a continuation of the above question

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the actual column numbers you want to copy in the `arrColCopy` array.  The code has it set for columns A,B,D,G,H,J which correspond to your header labeled Ref No, A,C,F,G,I

```
Sub CopyColumns()

Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim arrColCopy() As Variant
Dim col As Variant
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

'Column numbers to copy
arrColCopy = Array(1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10)

Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Procurement Plan ->PM40")  'Sheet to copy values from
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Management Summary ->PM40") 'Sheet to paste values to

lastRow = wsInput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

cnt = 1
For i = 2 To lastRow
  If wsInput.Cells(i, 1).Value <> wsInput.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
    cnt = cnt + 1
    For Each col In arrColCopy
      wsDest.Cells(cnt, col).Value = wsInput.Cells(i, col).Value
    Next col

  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It doesn't quite achieve what I want though.

Comment: @PriyankaDembla can you let me know what specifically it doesn't accomplish from your request?