# Check row Condition to copy and paste from 1 Workbook to the other

Tags: vba, excel

Please look at the attached image
[image]

This is just dummy data.

My requirement is

- If Internal Asset ID (Column B) is unique, Copy row regardless selected or not (Column F).
- If Internal Asset ID not unique i.e. same Internal Asset ID is present column B 
  more than once, see against which Internal Asset ID is Column F marked as selected & then copy only that row.
- Copied rows are: 3rd row,5th row, 7th, 8th, 9th row"

This data is in Workbook1:Sheet1 and I have to copy it to Workbook2:Sheet2 The mapping of copy & paste has to be like mentioned below -

```
WB1:Sheet1 A to WB2:Sheet2 A
WB1:Sheet1 B to WB2:Sheet2 B
WB1:Sheet1 N to WB2:Sheet2 C
WB1:Sheet1 X to WB2:Sheet2 D
WB1:Sheet1 Y to WB2:Sheet2 E
WB1:Sheet1 AY to WB2:Sheet2 G
WB1:Sheet1 C to WB2:Sheet2 H
WB1:Sheet1 D to WB2:Sheet2 I
WB1:Sheet1 E to WB2:Sheet2 J
WB1:Sheet1 F to WB2:Sheet2 K
WB1:Sheet1 BI to WB2:Sheet2 R
WB1:Sheet1 AT to WB2:Sheet2 S
WB1:Sheet1 AU to WB2:Sheet2 T
WB1:Sheet1 AV to WB2:Sheet2 U
WB1:Sheet1 AW to WB2:Sheet2 V
```

The pasting in Workbook2:Sheet2 has to start from "A12"

My attempt:

```
Sub cpyCol()
    Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim uR As Range
    Dim eNumStorage() As String ' initial storage array to take values
    Dim x As String

    Set wc = Sheets("Test")
    Set wa = Sheets("Test")
    lr = wc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim eNumStorage(1 To lr - 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = 3 To lr 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows
        If (Not IsEmpty(Cells(I, 2).Value)) Then ' checks to make sure the value isn't empty
            J = J + 1
            eNumStorage(J) = Cells(I, 2).Value ' to store values of internal Asset ID in an array
        End If
        If wc.Range("F" & I) = "Selected" Then 'check if column F is marked as selected
            If (uR Is Nothing) Then
                Set uR = Range(I & ":" & I)
            Else
                Set uR = Union(uR, Range(I & ":" & I))
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    uR.copy Destination:=wa.Range("A13")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Result (For testing I just tried copying & pasting from the same sheet to the same sheet)-**

- I am able to copy rows which are marked as selected in column F
- I am able to store the values of Internal Asset ID in column B in array eNumStorage()
- So I am able to copy 3rd and 5th row

**Where I need help -**

- Not able to copy 7th,8th and 9th row.

What I tried to copy 7th,8th and 9th row

```
 If eNumStorage(J) = eNumStorage(J + 1) Then
        If wc.Range("F" & I) = "Selected" Then 'check if column F is marked as selected
            If (uR Is Nothing) Then
                Set uR = Range(I & ":" & I)
            Else
                Set uR = Union(uR, Range(I & ":" & I))
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

**Issue -**
Not working for later rows

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your previous questions don’t have accepted answers - none of them helped you? Can you include your attempted code to solve the requirements?

Comment: Hello @jeepad. Thank you for your reply. I'll be more than happy to post my attempt here. And what may seem boring to you may be challenging for others. :) Also, as evident from my reputation, I am new to SO. Would appreciate an advice on how I can improve my question.

Comment: @paul bica . These were my attempts. Thank you for suggesting how to improve my question.

Comment: @PriyankaDembla Well, you posted your requirement, if that means you want us to fulfill that, this is not how this site works. We need a precise question that is well defined and not too broad and that we can answer: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) You didn't ask one yet. Try to explain what is wrong with your attempts, where you got errors and which? What do you expect and what does it do instead. If possible make a [mcve] to illustrate your issue. The more you explain the more likely is it to get a good answer.

Comment: @PEH . Thank you for your reply. I am sure I have learned how to improve my questions. I have edited it and tried to make it better. If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine which line has to be copied and which not you can use this formula
in column G

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B:B)>1,COUNTIFS(B:B,B:B,F:F,"Selected")=1,F:F<>"Selected"),"-","copy")
```

Now you could even use filters to filter by column G.

**Explanation**

- `COUNTIF(B:B,B:B)` counts the occurrences of the "AssetID". So this is a test for uniqueness if it is `>1` the ID is not unique.
- `COUNTIFS(B:B,B:B,F:F,"Selected")` counts the occurrences of non-unique "AssedIDs" that are "Selected". So if this is `=1` it means one of the IDs was marked as selected.
- `F:F<>"Selected"` means the ID was not selected

In total the formula means: Mark all IDs as `Copy` but sort out these which are …

- not unique
- AND not unique and not selected
- AND not selected

and this basically means, keep all marked as copy which are:

- unique
- OR non-unique and selected
- OR selected

---

**Or an example with VBA**
using pretty much the same formula.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle3") 'your worksheet

    Dim lRow As Long 'last used row
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Const fRow As Long = 3 'first row with data


    Dim i As Long
    For i = fRow To lRow 'run from first data row to last
        If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B" & fRow, "B" & lRow), ws.Range("B" & i)) > 1 And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("B" & fRow, "B" & lRow), ws.Range("B" & i), ws.Range("F" & fRow, "F" & lRow), "Selected") = 1 And _
           ws.Range("F" & i) <> "Selected") Then

            'copy this line

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to do the trick. But could you kindly explain the  `>1` and `=1` in the if? I read it online but thought would be clearer in the current context.

Comment: Could you kindly explain the if condition?

Comment: @PriyankaDembla See my edit. Basically the formula marks all as copy but sorts out the ones which **don't** meet any of the criteria (unique, non-unique but selected, selected). The VBA part uses the same technique.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured out a solution that does exactly what I wanted. Thank you @PEH for your help.

```
Sub cpyCol()
    Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, I As Long, J As Long, I2 As Long
    Dim uR As Range
    Dim wb, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim eNumStorage() As String ' initial storage array to take values
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Z003U8UC\Downloads\PP_Anan.xlsm")
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Procurement plan PM80 ->")
    Set wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-3).Row
    I2 = 11
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = 2 To lRow 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows
        If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B" & fRow, "B" & lRow), ws.Range("B" & I)) > 1 And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("B" & fRow, "B" & lRow), ws.Range("B" & I), ws.Range("AY" & fRow, "AY" & lRow), "Selected") = 1 _
        And ws.Range("AY" & I) <> "Selected") Then
'            If (uR Is Nothing) Then
'                Set uR = Range(I & ":" & I)
'            Else
'                Set uR = Union(uR, Range(I & ":" & I))
'            End If
            I2 = I2 + 1
            wa.Cells(I2, "A") = ws.Cells(I, "A")
            wa.Cells(I2, "B") = ws.Cells(I, "B")
            wa.Cells(I2, "C") = ws.Cells(I, "N")
            wa.Cells(I2, "D") = ws.Cells(I, "X")
            wa.Cells(I2, "E") = ws.Cells(I, "Y")
            wa.Cells(I2, "G") = ws.Cells(I, "AY")
            wa.Cells(I2, "H") = ws.Cells(I, "C")
            wa.Cells(I2, "I") = ws.Cells(I, "D")
            wa.Cells(I2, "J") = ws.Cells(I, "E")
            wa.Cells(I2, "K") = ws.Cells(I, "F")
            wa.Cells(I2, "R") = ws.Cells(I, "BI")
            wa.Cells(I2, "S") = ws.Cells(I, "AT")
            wa.Cells(I2, "T") = ws.Cells(I, "AU")
            wa.Cells(I2, "U") = ws.Cells(I, "AV")
            wa.Cells(I2, "V") = ws.Cells(I, "AW")
        End If
    Next I
    'uR.copy Destination:=ws.Range("A13")
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If this can further be improved speed wise please let me know.